# La función print me genera error ilógico en un escript de python. ¿Que está pasando aquí?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ayer mismo estuve usando este código sin ningún problema. Funcionaba perfectamente!!

```
import httplib2
import os
import sys

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow


# The CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE variable specifies the name of a file that contains
# the OAuth 2.0 information for this application, including its client_id and
# client_secret. You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from
# the Google Developers Console at
# https://console.developers.google.com/.
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
# For more information about using OAuth2 to access the YouTube Data API, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication
# For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"

# This variable defines a message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE is
# missing.
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:

   %s

with information from the Developers Console
https://console.developers.google.com/

For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
""" % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                   CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE))

# This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for read-only access to the authenticated
# user's account, but not other types of account access.
YOUTUBE_READONLY_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
  message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE,
  scope=YOUTUBE_READONLY_SCOPE)

storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
credentials = storage.get()

if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
  flags = argparser.parse_args()
  credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, flags)

youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
  http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))

# Retrieve the contentDetails part of the channel resource for the
# authenticated user's channel.
channels_response = youtube.channels().list(
  mine=True,
  part="contentDetails"
).execute()

for channel in channels_response["items"]:
  # From the API response, extract the playlist ID that identifies the list
  # of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
  uploads_list_id = channel["contentDetails"]["relatedPlaylists"]["uploads"]

  print ("Videos in list %s" % uploads_list_id)

  # Retrieve the list of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
  playlistitems_list_request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
    playlistId=uploads_list_id,
    part="snippet",
    maxResults=50
  )


  while playlistitems_list_request:
    playlistitems_list_response = playlistitems_list_request.execute()

    # Print information about each video.
    for playlist_item in playlistitems_list_response["items"]:
      title = playlist_item["snippet"]["title"]
      video_id = playlist_item["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"]
      print("%s # %s" % (video_id,title))


    playlistitems_list_request = youtube.playlistItems().list_next(
      playlistitems_list_request, playlistitems_list_response)

  print
```

Sin embargo hoy lo quíse volver a usar y me han salido este error:

```
$ py -3 "c:/Users/ivan/Desktop/Codigos_YouTube/2-listar_videos_id/get_video_id.py" >> id_all.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/ivan/Desktop/Codigos_YouTube/2-listar_videos_id/get_video_id.py", line 91, in <module>
    print("%s # %s" % (video_id,title))
  File "C:\Users\ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 18: character maps to <undefined>
```

La linea 91 y el caracter 19 se corresponde con esto

```
  print("%s # %s" % (video_id,title))
```

No sé que pasa exactamente pero si lo escribo así el error desaparace

```
  print("%s # %s" % ('video_id','title'))
```

Ahora que ponerlo así no tiene ninguna utilidad.
¿Alguien sabe que está pasando?

Comment: Bienvenido al mundo de las codificaciones internacionales, el problema es que seguramente `title` esta con alguna códifcación que no puede mostrarse por la terminal. Una forma de resolverlo, podría ser: `print("%s # %s" % (video_id,repr(title)))`

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar!! Lo acabo de probar pero sigue dando el mismo error!! ¿Alguna otra ídea?

Comment: Entonces, prueba en todo caso hacer `print(title.encode('utf-8'))` , a ver que ocurre.

Comment: Perfecto!! Eso si ha funcionado!! Muchísimas gracias!! :-)

Comment: ¿Hay alguna forma de quitar la 'b' que sale ahora delante del titulo? Sale algo así... b'Titulo'... aunque mirando por el lado bueno por lo menos funciona

Comment: El tema del `b` es por que en realidad el `encode` transforma tu cadena en bytes. El problema en realidad se soluciona configurando el encoding default de la salida estándar mediante una variable de entorno `PYTHONIOENCODING`, en un rato formalizo una respuesta

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias, esperaré por ella... también veo algunas cosas como esta \xe2\x80\x93 en algunos titulos, creo que se correspondo con los acentos y con simbolos como el AND '&' o la admiración '!' ¿Tal vez se solucione usando otra codificación? Aunque el 99% de ellos se ven bastante bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que aparentemente estás recibiendo caracteres multibyte, posiblemente `utf-8`, el tema es que la consola de `python` por defecto no tiene una codificación (`cp850`) capaz de mostrar estos caracteres. La manera más fácil de resolverlo es configurando la variable de entorno: [`PYTHONIOENCODING`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING).

Por ejemplo en windows:

```
set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
```

O en Linux:

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
```

Una forma rápida de probar que esto funciona es testear unno de los caracteres que te dan problema, el `u\u0308`:

En Windows podrías hacer:

```
set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 && python -c "import sys;print(sys.stdout.encoding);print(u'u\u0308')"
```

O en Linux algo parecido:

```
PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8;python -c 'import sys;print(sys.stdout.encoding);print(u"u\u0308")'
```

Comment: Bueno, dependiendo de en que consola lo haga  tengo un resultado u otro.. En el CMD de windows tengo esta salida (utf-8 y una u con un cuadrado). En Cygwin64 me sale esto ('cp1252' y el mismo mensaje de error por el cual hice el este post - UnicodeEncodeError). Y en la consola de Python me dice invalid syntax.... la consola de Python también  me da otro error con el script ('unicodescape'). Tengo que decir que puede ser culpa mia por que es la primera vez que la uso y es posible que no sepa usarla, siempre lanzo los scripts desde el CMD

Comment: Por el momento él mejor que me ha funcionado es el utf-8, probé este también 'cp1252' y el latin1 pero, el mejor es el utf-8... no muestra los acentos, ni algunos simbolos pero la mayoria se ve bien el 99.9%  y prefiero esto a nada que es lo que tenia al principio. Te doy las gracias por tu yuda otra vez @Patricio Moracho.

Comment: Por cierto... la 'b' esa de b'Titilo' al final se puede quitar de forma fácil? O tengo que hacer uso de funciones de manejo de strings para quitarlo?

Comment: @IvánRodríguez, en primer lugar debieras averiguar en la documentación de la API cual es el encoding que deberías esperar y configurarlo como te muestro en la respuesta. Por otro lado, te aclaro que sí configuras tal como te dije, simplemente deberías poder hacer `print(title_id)` sin problemas (siempre que el encoding sea el adecuado). El `b` que te aparece es producto de uno de mis comentarios para que pruebes convertir en bytes la cadena, pero con esta solución no tienees necesidad de hacerlo.

Comment: Lo intentaré, la verdad es que Google no da mucha información al respecto. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update?hl=es-419  Y desgraciadamente no tengo mucha idea de Python, mi intención príncipal era darle un uso práctico a estos códigos y no experimentar con el API.  Pero debido a todos los problemas que me han dado no me a quedado otro remedio y tengo la suerte de que sé un poco de C++ y gracias a eso, con un poco de intuición, y la ayuda de esta comunidad he ido resolviendo los problemas. Sería estupendo que funcionará como tu dices. Lo intentaré configurar!!